# Looking for recommendation for naming conventions for different REST resource representations

Tags: rest, spring-mvc, jersey, resteasy

When using any REST framework (jersey, resteasy, spring-mvc) most of the time the (persistent) model classes are not the same as the exposed REST resource representations.
Even most of the time the incoming json representation (for e.g. create and update) is different then the outgoing json representation (e.g. list, get, ..).

I'm looking for some good naming conventions to sort this out.

Example structure:

```
+-- my.comp.domain.Customer
+-- my.comp.rest.resource.CustomerResource (or CustomerController)
```

The CustomerResource will internally use the Customer to persist and retrieve data.
But to the outside (Request + Response objects) it will use a little bit different structure.

What I did now is:

```
+-- my.comp.rest.representation.CustomerRequest 
+-- my.comp.rest.representation.SimpleCustomerResponse
+-- my.comp.rest.representation.SimpleCustomerCollectionResponse
+-- my.comp.rest.representation.ExtendedCustomerResponse
```

Those are basically simple POJO containing just fields. The REST framework used will just use these to convert it to json.

Anyone else using different namings? I'm open for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having Request, Response as separate try to use common basic representation to represent most and add additional based on needs.

POST /customers/  - class could be 'CustomerRepresentation / CustomerContract / CustomerRp/ representation.CustomerModel'

GET /customers/{id} - Return the same CustomerRepresentation or the above

PUT - same as well

GET /customers/ - CustomerListRepresentation or same

Links could be attached to its corresponding objects as optional things for create.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Whenever you return list when you dont pass customer id placeholder then your url should describe list i.e. GET /customers

Comment: otherwise GET /customer/{id}

Comment: Updated the URL plurally for all cases. It is not required to differentiate them based on singular/plural, it will be enough to define all of them plural to make the api simple. It is up to each individual to make their choice rather than confusing with too many conventions.